# Change Default Language from Chinese to English

Tags: android, webview

I have cloned Android WebView code https://github.com/AlexTam930/uploadimage
the app is working but when i click on choose file, the option opens in chinese language [image]

I am new to android, trying to convert a website to AndroidApp through WebView.

in my source code where will i find the language change code??

Comment: There is just one strings.xml file in the source and it seems to be in Chinese. Switching the language will thus not help. You must provide also English strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MainActivity.java`, line 169-171, there is this code:

```
    alertDialog.setTitle("请选择操作");
    // gallery, camera.
    String[] options = {"相册", "拍照"};
```

Replace the Chinese with English translations and you are done:

```
    alertDialog.setTitle("Please select an operation:");
    // gallery, camera.
    String[] options = {"Photo Album", "Camera"};
```

There are also other strings in `MainActivity.java`. I will provide a translation here:

Line 180, 196, 205:

请去"设置"中开启本应用的图片媒体访问权限 -> Please go to "Settings" to allow this app to access your photo album.

Line 215:

请去"设置"中开启本应用的相机权限 -> Please go to "Settings" to allow this app to access the camera.

Line 231:

请去"设置"中开启本应用的相机和图片媒体访问权限 -> Please go to "Settings" to allow this app to access the camera and the photo album.

Line 327:

```
String strMessage = "请允许使用\"" + permissionsMsg.substring(1).toString() + "\"权限, 以正常使用APP的所有功能.";
```

This line is basically creating a string that says "Please allow the access of XXX, so as to be able to use all the features of this app", where XXX is the string `permissionMsg`, which is constructed using the if statements a few lines before. This uses the strings in `strings.xml`, so you should probably go there and replace them with translations as well.

Answer (score 2):

Please check once git cloned code. There are some String resources with Chineses lang.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">UploadImage</string>

    <string name="permission_camera">摄像头</string>
    <string name="permission_storage">文件</string>
    <string name="permission_accounts">信息</string>
    <string name="permission_phone">状态</string>
    <string name="permission_location">定位</string>
    <string name="permission_audio">录音</string>

</resources>
```

You can do one thing copy those strings and Translate those accordingly.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">UploadImage</string>

    <string name="permission_camera">Camera</string>
    <string name="permission_storage">File</string>
    <string name="permission_accounts">Information</string>
    <string name="permission_phone">Status</string>
    <string name="permission_location">Positioning</string>
    <string name="permission_audio">Recording</string>

</resources>
```

Also, check if there are some string added in Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

you can get android phone language from setting and send it by post request to your web and change your web language

to get current language in android ,use this:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```